# C++ CLI pointer to pointer to a native object

Tags: pointers, c++-cli

I have a managed class that has a member that is a pointer to native object. Like this (not a real code):

```
ref class ManagedClass {

private:
    NativeClass* ptr = nullptr;

};
```

I need to initialize this pointer to point to a valid object by calling a native method, that takes pointer-to-pointer:

```
void native_init(NativeClass** nc);
```

But when I try to get this pointer-to-pointer for ptr by:

```
native_init(&ptr);
```

VS shows a message that

> argument of type interion_ptr is incompatible with
>   parameter of type NativeClass**

So, how can I get pointer to that pointer?

This code works:

```
NativeClass *local_ptr;
native_init(&local_ptr);
ptr = local_ptr;
```

But when I try to delete it like this:

```
delete ptr
```

The application crashes saying that I try to "to read or write protected memory". What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Well, a managed object can be moved around in memory, which is the reason why the compiler doesn't let you take an address to it - that address *will* become outdated sooner or later.

You can take an address to a managed reference type object after *pinning* it. The simplest would be to use `pin_ptr`, the object will be guaranteed not to move in memory until the `pin_ptr` goes out of scope.

So you can write this:

```
auto managedObject = gcnew ManagedClass();
pin_ptr<NativeClass*> pinnedNativePtr = &managedObject->ptr;
native_init(pinnedNativePtr);
```

But make sure the `NativeClass**` won't be kept around and accessed *after* the call to `native_init`.

---

As to your attempt, it's certainly valid. But you're getting an `AccessViolationException` most probably because `native_init` didn't use the `new` operator to create the object, or used a different runtime. If you're trying to use a library, it should provide some sort of `native_free` function, so use that instead of `delete`.

Comment: No, native_init uses new, I can guarantee it. The exception occurs if I use pinned ptr.

Comment: You may also have a double-delete issue, so you may want to debug that. Also, make sure the `new` and `delete` both use the same underlying runtime library.